# How to set --no-sandbox for headless portable chrome

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, google-chrome-headless, web-testing, testcafe

I want to run **TestCafe** on **headless portable chrome** with `--no-sandbox` flag

How can I do this?

I can run it without a flag

```
testcafe chrome:path/to/portable/chrome:headless test.js
```

But when I try set flag it doesn't work

```
testcafe chrome:path/to/portable/chrome:headless --no-sandbox test.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Running with quotes `''` helps

```
testcafe 'chrome:path/to/portable/chrome:headless --no-sandbox' test.js
```

I've closed my question

Comment: You are absolutely right. You can also take a look at the [Starting browser with arguments](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#starting-browser-with-arguments) documentation section - "Enclose the browser call and its arguments in quotation marks".